# Can I force attributes onto children?

Tags: reactjs

Not referring to the magic `props.children`, but can I force a child element to have specific attributes (or added values to an attribute) on the top-level element it produces? Example scenario:

```
const Button = 
  (props) => 
    ( <button type="button" id={props.id} className={['btn'].concat(props.classNames)}>{props.children}</button>);
```

would love to not have to do the `classNames` prop, let the parent force extra classes down without child interaction/involvement/consent.

Even better if it would allow things, besides just extra css classes, but that's the current target.

Is it possible to do this to the children without them knowing?

Comment: This might help: https://www.amazon.com/Parenting-Dummies-Sandra-Hardin-Gookin/dp/0764554182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for (*use ES6 spread operator*):

```
const Button = (props) => (<button {...props}>{props.children}</button>);
```

It passes all the props that've been specified on `Button` component down to `<button>` element, so in case if you specify:

```
<Button className="my-class" id="10">submit</Button>
```

The `<button>` element will receive: `<button className="my-class" id="10" >submit</button>`

**Update**: If you want to pass only some props and not all of them, then you might consider assigning an object to a top-level component and use it as props on a children one.

```
const Button = (props) => (<button {...props.data}>{props.children}</button>)

<Button data={{ id: 10, className: 'my-class' }}>submit</Button>
```

Comment: since I always saw this example (`{...props}`) with the magic `{props.children}` addendum, which I have never used, I always thought it had to do with children. This is terrific, if that works the way it appears to, let me try it out.

Comment: feels like the spread operator is overkill, and a poor one to boot, you can't use a blacklist I bet, you have to chuck all properties even the ones that shouldn't go to the child's children.
I'd really like to be able to just pass down things like parent-passed `data-*` attributes. or merge `classNames` onto children

Comment: if you need to filter out some props you can apply filter to props:

Comment: however, to avoid writing lots of custom code, I'd personally pass an object on a top-level component and then pass that object down as a props to a children component using spread operator. That's what many libraries do when they need to accept some configuration.

Comment: `<Button data={{id: 10, other-data: 'some data'}}>submit</Button>`

Comment: your edit is where my attempts went next after reading your answer, and it looks like what I'm going to use. I really like it. I called mine `{...props.spread}` which I think may be a better name for what it does/is.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone each child using [React.cloneElement()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement), which allows you to merge in your own props...

```
React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, { newProp: 1, otherProp: 'XYZ' });
});
```

...so, yours might look something like this:

```
const Button = (props) => {
  const className = ['btn'].concat(props.classNames).join(' ');

  <button type="button" id={props.id} className={className}>
    {
      React.Children.map(children, child => (
        React.cloneElement(child, { className })
      ))  
    }
  </button>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can either use `{...this.props}` or use refs to apply the class imperatively in `componentDidMount` / `componentDidUpdate` of the parent class.

However I'd really try not to use either approach. The current version of React warns when unknown properties are set on a DOM node and `{...this.props}` leads you often there. The imperative approach is also not good, because it breaks the functional data flow and basically makes using React obsolete.

I'd really try to be very explicit about what features / looks you want from a component and specify them strictly via props. That means also putting `className`, `style` and other attributes that seem trivial there. Often it's also helpful to use more semantic props: E.g. `colorScheme="confirm"`, `size="big"`, `type="outline"` are examples what could be useful for a `Button` component. That way it's possible to avoid some repetition when using the button across multiple places.

If you tell me more about your specific use case, I think there could be a good solution.